# "with a lamp and one wish left" - is that a quotation or allusion? And what does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Arsenal won the FA Cup and now a YouGov projection for the Times shows the Conservatives losing their majority: somewhere there's a Jeremy Corbyn with a lamp and one wish left.< (New Statesman)

Comment: It helps if you know that [Jeremy Corbyn supports Arsenal](https://www.dreamteamfc.com/c/news-gossip/181615/revealed-jeremy-corbyn-spends-loads-parliamentary-time-supporting-arsenal/)

Comment: @lirmont the link provided by Henry puts the sentence in context and you might like to reassess your interpretation: the **allusion** to the lamp and the wish is very imaginative use of the language indeed _ *Arsenal won the FA Cup and now a YouGov projection for the Times shows the Conservatives losing their majority:* _  In the context of the political background of the person in question and his support of Arsenal, we might be justified to interpret that **he has already "got his wish" (fulfilled) twice** and now has a lamp, a genie and a wish left,  which is a very nice position to be in!!

Comment: There is a concept that a genie's lamp provides 3 wishes. Regardless of context, the suggestion is that the person who found the lamp has only one wish left. Whether that's a good or bad situation remains to be seen. For example, maybe it was frivolous to have presumably spent a wish on a football team winning. Additionally, a projection doesn't actually mean the projected outcome has happened at that point. Supposedly, genies are tricky, and, if it looks like the person got everything that they wanted with wishes to spare, that third wish may be their undoing. Fanciful speculation all around.

Comment: Simply to amplify @English Student -- Corbyn's first wish was to see Arsenal win (fulfilled); his second wish was that the Conservative poll-lead would drop precipitously (fulfilled); his third wish is that he will become Prime Minister (pending).

Comment: Possibly the reference should be specifically to the Disney version of Aladdin, since in the original _Arabian Nights_, Aladdin isn't restricted in the number of his wishes.  The "three wishes" element derives from stories in which a fairy is either captured, or is returning a favour, and responds by allowing the captor/benefactor (only) three wishes.

Comment: @Robin Hamilton the concept that if the first 2 wishes were granted then the third might well be an undoing (as noted by lirmont  in the earlier comment) is also very striking. That reminds me of the  famous / notorious short story **"the Monkey's Paw"** where a frivolous wish for good luck is followed by a tragedy and so on. Many communities worldwide have a myth / belief that random good luck is followed by bad -- there apparently being a fear in many cultures that undeserved good fortune may get 'punished.'

Comment: An undoing is easily done. Searching for "a lamp and one wish left." turns up the book "Home for Christmas: A Novel, By Linda Lael Miller, Catherine Mulvany, Julie Leto, Roxanne St. Claire": https://books.google.ca/books?id=64PB3PihPqYC&pg=PA207&lpg=PA207&dq=with+a+lamp+and+one+wish+left.&source=bl&ots=iXe5vOzwpk&sig=GPxJ2w232dk8wfFU94u8pBpMpVE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYn-HR7e_XAhUM-2MKHSvIDz8Q6AEISDAK#v=onepage&q=with%20a%20lamp%20and%20one%20wish%20left.&f=false - It points out that the 3rd wish can undo everything or modify a single prior wish. Only wishing for more wishes is prohibited.

Answer (score 2):

The entire passage is a quotation from *New Statesman*—but the phrase *a lamp and one wish left* is an allusion to a genie's lamp, if not Aladdin's.

Per Merriam-Webster, an allusion is "an implied or indirect reference especially in literature."

The entire passage implies that two out of three wishes have been used up in order to grant the events described. (Perhaps each wish carefully used to grant an otherwise unlikely outcome, or perhaps used unwisely to grant something that would have happened anyway).

The additional part of *somewhere there's a Jeremy Corbyn* is not an allusion in its own right (the UK celebrity is directly named, and so neither an implied nor indirect reference). However, it could make the overall expression an *allegory* of a particular sentiment.

Again per Merriam-Webster, an allegory is "the expression by means of symbolic fictional figures and actions of truths or generalizations about human existence" or "a symbolic representation." (Jeremy Corbyn is not a fictional figure, but the complete set of imagery is fictional.)